# Apache stops processing requests (mod_wsgi?)

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-10.04

At some point my site, running on Apache2 with mod_wsgi just *stops processing requests*. The *connection to server is maintained and client waits* for responce, but it never is returned by apache. The server at this time is *at 0% CPU*, and nothing is processing. I think, apache just sends request to queue and never gets them out of there.
When I perform `apache2ctl graceful` the problem **does not** resolve. Only after `apache2ctl restart`.

My site is a 4 instance wsgi application of Pyramid and 2 instances of Zope 3. It is running normaly and does not have speed problems, that I am aware of.

versions:
   Ubuntu 10.04
   apache2  2.2.14-5ubuntu8.9
   libapache2-mod-wsgi 2.8-2ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using embedded mode to run the multiple applications and you are using third party C extensions that have problems in sub interpreters, resulting in potential deadlock. Else your code is internally deadlocking or blocking on external services and never returning, causing exhaustion of available processes/threads.

For a start, you should look at using daemon mode and delegate each web application to a distinct daemon process group and then forcing each to run in the main interpreter.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Otherwise use debugging tips described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques

for getting stack traces about what application is doing.